# Problem with rosmake rgbdslam and g2o error

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that I set up everything right, because it was working on my two other computer.

Using Ubuntu 12.01LTS and ROS Fuerte.

I installed libg2o, and kept getting g2o errors whenever im trying to install rgbdslam. I did rosdep check and all dep are satisfied. arggh...

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/8ad5e295639b0b5c0e0a1ffe09019e4a

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49310/problem-with-rosmake-rgbdslam-and-g2o-error./) by [Jtbak](https://answers.ros.org/users/3681/jtbak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/38989/rgbdslam-with-ros-fuerte-installed/#39168). You have to make some modifications to get RGBDSLAM to cooperate in Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0